# Q&A Web Part Help

Tags: web-part

I am a novice at Sharepoint.  I believe I am using Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint designer 2010.  I do log into Sharepoint through a web browser if that helps at all.  My boss is requesting to add a Q&A section to our Sharepoint page.  He wants users to be able to submit a question and receive email notifications when a question is submitted.  When he answers the question he would like the option to post the question to the Q&A page and email the user the answer OR just email the user the answer without posting it to the Q&A Page.

-I was thinking that a form could be used to submit the quest (only need Name Field, email field and question field.
-that a list could be used to list questions the boss wants posted
However, I do not know how to make it come together and to implement all the little nuances that make it user friendly.  THANK YOU!

Comment: 1. Who to receive notification when a question is submitted?

Comment: 2. Is your boss only one who will answer questions?

Comment: 3. No one to see the questions till they get answered?

Comment: Sorry about the late response, I've been out of pocket.  The boss and 2-3 assistants would recieve some type of notification that there is a pending question submitted.  These members will tend to rotate every so often; so being able to change them would be a must.

Comment: I am actually using SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2010.  Sorry about the mix up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom list as Q&A. In the list, create a required column called “Question” for users to enter their questions. And create another column called “Answer” for the assistants to enter their answers.

Then, create a workflow using SharePoint Designer and make it start automatically when an item is created in this list. In this workflow, Email assistants.

After that, we need another workflow to email the user who asked the question. Start this workflow when an item is modified and use the condition to check if the “Answer” column is not blank. If it is not blank, email the “Created By” user.